# Outlook vsto - properties handling

Tags: c#, outlook, properties, vsto, outlook-redemption

i have a problem with MailItem properties in a Outlook VSTO. I add some custom properties to a previously exported .msg mail with e.g. redemption in the following way:

```
SafeMailItem smi = new SafeMailItem {
    Item = mailItem
};
int propertyId = smi.GetIDsFromNames(PROPERTY_GUID, "anyID");
smi.Fields[propertyId] = propertyString;
```

This property is removed and i cant find it again if i click on sending the mail. I checked this with Outlook Spy and before i send the mail the property is available but after i click on send (and e.g. cancel the send) the property is gone.

I also tried to call MailItem.Save() (at any time) but it has no effect apart from the fact that the .msg file includes the mail edits :). The same behavior is given if i use MailItem.PropertyAccessor directly.

Can anybody explain me why the properties are removed and how to fix this issue?

Thanks a lot for support

*Outlook version: 16.0.0.13530 (64-bit); Visual Studio Professional 2019 16.8.4*

Comment: Do you save the message afterwards?

Comment: Also keep in mind that it is easier to open and modify MSG files using RDOSession.GetMessageFromMsgFIle.

Comment: Hi, yes i tried to save the mail at any time but the properties are no longer set as soon as i click on send.
What i didn't understand is that if i use mailitem.userproperties the issue doesn't exists but for that there is another issue if i set properties before saving it as msg, reopen this msg and the properties are not available anymore.

Comment: Do you mean the property is not set on a received message? Or on message in the Sent Items folder?

Comment: If i click on send and cancel the sending by code the property is gone

Comment: Are you sure OOM sees that there was a change (otherwise MailItem.Save won't do anything)? Have you tried to "dirty" the MailItem object?